# Creating dynamic list box in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to make a list created from a sql select statement that will populate into a multiselect listbox.

Trick is, the SQL select statement will return different results over time. This means the list could be 5 rows one day and 10 rows another.

How can I create this using vba?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. As written, it will not receive much attention (and could be closed).

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough:

1. Create a Listbox in an excel file.
2. Extract the items, you want to populate the listbox with, onto a seperate worksheet called "shtData".
3. Make a named range "myListboxItems" of the range in 2.
4. Write some vba using classic ado to extract data from server to "shtData" - it will need to update the named range's target range.
5. Link the list box to the named range.